# Relating two definitions of the measure of a solid angle

Tags: geometry

In a computer graphics text I am reading, they give the following definitions:
A solid angle $\Omega$ at a point $p \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is a measurable subset of the unit sphere about $P$, and the measure of $\Omega$ is the area of  $\Omega$.

If $T$ is a shape in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $p$ is a point not in $T$, then the solid angle subtended by $T$ at $p$ is the area of the radial projection of $T$ onto a unit sphere centered at $p$. The author then states if $U$ is a subset of a sphere of radius $r$ about $P$ of area $A$, then according to this definition one can show that the solid angle represented by $U$ is $\frac {A}{r^2}$.

Suppose we have such a $U$ of area $A$, then if I project this set onto the unit sphere centered at $p$, as opposed to the sphere of radius $r$, how do you get that the area scales in $\frac {1} {r^2}$? This scaling is given as the definition in some cases of a solid angle (i.e. the definition of the solid angle is not put in terms strictly of measurable sets on a unit sphere, but rather a sphere of arbitrary radius).

For instance, if we project a sphere of radius $R$ onto the unit sphere, we will get an area of $\frac{4 \pi R^2} { R^2} = 4 \pi$ , but I'm not sure why this is true for a general measurable subset of the sphere of radius $R$.

Comment: What is your definition of area?

Comment: @MoisheKohan from multivariable calculus for a surface $S$ with parametrization $f(u,v)$ for $(u,v) \in I$,  it would be $\int \int _{I}|| f_u \times f_v || du dv$

Comment: @MoisheKohan I have also studied the Jordan Measure from measure theory.

Comment: So, did you try either one of these definitions to verify that scaling by $a$ changes area by $a^2$?

Comment: @MoisheKohan well I thought to project a point from an arbitrary sphere of radius $R$ to a sphere of radius $1$ (both centered around the same point), we simply divide by the norm of each point, but each point on the outer sphere has norm $R$, rather than $R^2$, so not sure.

Comment: @MoisheKohan then again for a modified parametrization $g(u,v) = 1/R f(u,v)$, the cross product in the integral will scale in $1 /R^2$, do I have this right?